# Android studio 2.3.2 gradle issue

Tags: android, android-studio

I am fairly new to Android. Installed Android studio 2.3.2. Now I have created a sample project.

But the popup of building gradle project info is shown forever.

[image]

Comment: Try to import existing project if it's work let me know....and post screen shot while gredle build...

Comment: I avoid this by running `gradlew assembleDebug` via command line so the IDE doesnt try to download the dependencies, cache them and try to build the project. It is much faster via command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting gradle folder within your Project Folder. Then close and reopen your project in Android studio.

Comment: Thanks @Vimal. the problem got solved automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Go to ***c:users\UserName\.gredle\wrapper\dists\gredle-version-all\a4w5fzrkeut1ox56xslb49grt\gradle-(version)-all.zip*** path

If **gradle-(version)-all.zip** file is not available then download the file **gradle-(version)-all.zip** that **matches to gradle-(version)-all.zip.lck** from this Link http://services.gradle.org/distributions/

Paste Downloaded file in to **c:users\UserName\.gredle\wrapper\dists\gredle-version-all\a4w5fzrkeut1ox56xslb49grt**

Close Android studio if open and open again and try to create new Project or import Existing project

i hope it will work for you...